# How to target a single image map area when multiple image maps are on the same page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have three image maps on a page, and want to select the area for each map.

Map 1 HTML

```
<img src="map1.jpg" width="100" height="10" border="0" usemap="#Map1" />
<map name="Map1" id="Map1">
  <area shape="rect" coords="609,235,834,335" href="test1.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe"/>
</map>
```

Map 2 HTML

```
<img src="map2.jpg" width="100" height="10" border="0" usemap="#Map2" />
<map name="Map2" id="Map2">
  <area shape="rect" coords="609,235,834,335" href="test2.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe"/>
</map>
```

Map 3 HTML

```
<img src="map3.jpg" width="100" height="10" border="0" usemap="#Map3" />
<map name="Map3" id="Map3">
  <area shape="rect" coords="609,235,834,335" href="test3.htm" class="fancybox" rel="iframe"/>
</map>
```

I've tried these selectors:

```
$('#Map1 > area.fancybox') // function 
$('map > #Map1 > area.fancybox') // function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first selector is accurate for targeting a specific map:

- [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqTmt/1/)

If you want to select *any* area you could simply use:

```
$('area');
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, new tool to help me test and learn from JS/jQuery with that. :)