# Image Map Wont react to JQuery UI ID

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have an image map:

```
 <html>
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" src="MapFinal_002.png" border="0" width="500" height="500" orgWidth="500" orgHeight="500" usemap="#image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-08-11-113524">
    <area alt="Pioneer Mexico" title="Mexico" href="#" shape="rect" coords="143,372,193,422" target="_self" id="Mexico" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="498,498,500,500" alt="Image Map" title="Image Map" />
</map>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#Mexico', function() {
         $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the JQuery-ui Dialog part to show by usig the following script:

Note the "#Mexico"in the code. I do not understand why, since #Mexico is an id in the image map, the jquery wont notice it as a css id. Right now, it doesn't do anything

Comment: id is not valid for an `area` element. Try using a class instead. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717813/how-to-target-a-single-image-map-area-when-multiple-image-maps-are-on-the-same-p

Comment: I tried a class as well and it didn't work

Comment: Did you wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues here. Not sure what the `onclick` attributes were doing in your markup, so removed those. Also below we are waiting until the document is ready. Also, you are right it does work with the `id` on the `area` element. Hopefully this will help:

HTML:

```
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" src="/assets/site/img/MapFinal_002.png" border="0" width="500" height="500" orgWidth="500" orgHeight="500" usemap="#image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2014-08-11-113524" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-08-11-113524">
    <area alt="Pioneer Mexico" title="Mexico" href="#" shape="rect" coords="143,372,193,422" target="_self" id="Mexico" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="498,498,500,500" alt="Image Map" title="Image Map" />
</map>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
    $("#Mexico").on("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deyeozex/2/)

Comment: I used your code but I am still unable to get a dialog to show. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deyeozex/1/ Does my example work for you? working here in Chrome

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console? Have you tried a different browser? When I click the image map the dialog opens. Not sure what you mean by "all I get is the div code in the browser"

Comment: I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/deyeozex/2/ with an image that should load. Click the eagle/snake and it should open the dialog??

Comment: It turns out your code was working fine, but the website design provider we use wouldn't' allow the http references to the JQuery libraries. That's what caused my confusion